# Query aggregate faster than MAX

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a fairly large table in which one of the columns is a date column. The query I execute is as follows.

```
select max(date) from tbl where date < to_date('10/01/2010','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

That is, I want to find the cell value closest to and less than a particular date value. This takes considerable time because of the max on the large table. Is there a faster way to do this? maybe using LAST_VALUE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Add an index to the date column. Simply put, an index allows the database engine to store information about the data so it will speed up most queries where that column is one of the clauses. Info here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm

2) Consider adding a second clause to the query. You have `where date < to_date('10/01/2010','MM/DD/YYYY')` now, why not change it to:

```
where date < to_date('10/01/2010','MM/DD/YYYY') and date > to_date('09/30/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

since this will reduce the number of scanned rows.

Comment: I would vote a +1 (for part 1) and a -1 (for part 2) on this answer if I could.

Comment: @ypercube It's all about context :) The OP was not yet aware of indexes, we've all been there at some point. To embark on training up someone on Stackoverflow is unrealistic, so in the meantime I offered a quick win. If Oracle's engine would not give any performance improvement due to the addition of a second clause, then I've learnt something about Oracle today :)

Comment: The second query will return no rows because there is no date between Sep-30th and Oct-1st.

Comment: I created an index and its awesome. Thanks!

Comment: And if there is no index, there is no performance gain, but loss because the engine has to check 2 conditions for every row.

Comment: @ypercube depending on how the Oracle engine considers the time part of a date, the second clause may still yield results :) Also, there should be a negligible performance gain because the aggregate function does not have to consider any rows that are not desired.

Comment: Yes, you could be right. I thought that `to_date()` returns a `date` without any `time` part. Not really much exprerience in Oracle. Still (nit-picking) your 2nd query will not return anything if there are no data in that range while the 1st will. SO, they are not equivalent in all instances.

Answer (score 4):

Put an index on the date column and the query should be plenty fast.

Comment: I dont follow. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Aks: Not sure how I would elaborate that… Is there an index on that column?

Comment: @Aks: If you're working with databases and don't know what an index is, then you're lacking some *serious* basic knowledge. I can only recommend taking half an hour or so and reading a chapter on the topic of indexes and how you create them in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select date from (
    select date from tbl where date < to_date('10/01/2010','MM/DD/YYYY') order by date desc
) where rownum = 1
```

Comment: This is taking pretty long as well. But interesting idea. Thanks!